# create buffer around locator-derived point

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point, buffer, dojo

I am trying to create a buffer around a point derived from a locator search, using this example:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm
..but I am getting no results.  I am not sure how to pass the correct information from the locator result graphic to the buffer functions (sorry if this has been answered before, i couldn't find a solution).

Thanks, code is below..Jason

```
    ////////////// locator func ///////////////////////////////////

  function showLocatorResults(candidates) 
  {
    var candidate;
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    symbol.setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE);
    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([153, 0, 51, 0.75]));
    var geom, graphic;

    dojo.every(candidates, function (candidate) {

        if (candidate.score > 80) 
        {
           // extent code removed for brevity
            var attributes = { address: candidate.address, score: candidate.score,    locatorName: candidate.attributes.Loc_name };
            geom = candidate.location;
            graphic = new esri.Graphic(geom, symbol, attributes);

            map.graphics.add(graphic);
            return false; 
        }
    });

    doBuffer(graphic);
    }


     ////////// buffer funcs ////////////////////////////////////////////////
     function doBuffer(g) {
    //map.graphics.clear();

    bufferParams = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
    bufferParams.distances = [100];         
    bufferParams.geometries =  [g.geometry] ; // problem here?

    bufferParams.unit = esri.tasks.BufferParameters.UNIT_FOOT;
    bufferParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
    geometrySvc.buffer (bufferParams, showBuffer);
}

function showBuffer(geometries) {

  var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
    esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
      esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
      new dojo.Color([0,0,255,0.65]), 2
    ),
    new dojo.Color([0,0,255,0.35])
  );

  dojo.forEach(geometries, function(geometry) {
    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry,symbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
  });


}
```

Comment: I should add that I added the proxy page code in my init function, also taken from ESRI examples:          //identify proxy page to use if the toJson payload to the geometry service is greater than 2000 characters.
        //If this null or not available the buffer operation will not work.  Otherwise it will do a http post to the proxy.

        
esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/proxy/proxy.ashx";
esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example that geocodes and address/place and then buffers the first result:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/esri/css/esri.css" />

    <style>
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      h3 { margin: 0 0 5px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #444; }
      .shadow {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
      }
      #map{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #feedback {
        background: #fff;
        bottom: 30px;
        color: #444;
        position: absolute;
        font-family: arial;
        height: 80px;
        left: 30px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 40;
      }
    </style>
    <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
    <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/"></script>
    <script>
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
      dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");
      dojo.require("esri.map");
      dojo.require("esri.tasks.locator");

      var map, locator;
      function init() {
        // why write a lot of javascript code when you can use arcgis.com to author your webmap?
        var webmapId = "8ca10201ec3d4c2a8e2e628df59c8c54";

        //create map
        var mapDeferred = esri.arcgis.utils.createMap(webmapId, "map", {
          mapOptions: { slider: false }
        });

        locator = new esri.tasks.Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");

        dojo.connect(dijit.byId("locate"), "onClick", function() {
          var address = dojo.byId("address").value;
          console.log("address: ", address);
          if ( ! address ) {
            alert("Please enter an address to geocode.");
            return;
          }
          locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
          var geocode = locator.addressToLocations({
            address: { "SingleLine": address },
            outFields: ["*"]
          });

          geocode.then(function(results) {
            console.log("got results: ", results);
            // add the results to the map
            dojo.forEach(results, function(r) {
              map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(
                r.location, new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(), r.attributes
              ));
            });
            console.log("added graphics...now buffer the first one");
            bufferLocation(results[0]);
          }, function(error) {
            console.log("geocode failed: ", error);
          });
        });

        mapDeferred.addCallback(function (response) {
          map = response.map;
          dojo.connect(dijit.byId("map"), "resize", map, map.resize);
        });
      }

      function bufferLocation(place) {
        var bufferParams = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
        bufferParams.geometries = [ place.location ];
        bufferParams.distances = [ 5 ]; // 5 km
        bufferParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
        bufferParams.unit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_KILOMETER;

        var gs = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
        var buffer = gs.buffer(bufferParams);
        buffer.then(function(buffers) {
          console.log("got buffers: ", buffers);
          dojo.forEach(buffers, function(b) {
            map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(
              b, new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol()
            ));
          });
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("error doing buffer...", error);
        });
      }
      dojo.ready(init);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="tundra">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false"
         style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
      <div id="map"
           data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'">

        <div id="feedback" class="shadow">
          <h3>Locate and address then buffer.</h3>
          <div id="info">
            <input type="text" id="address" value="Wrigley Field">
            <button dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="locate">Locate</button> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that no proxy is used. If you're buffering a single point, a proxy isn't necessary as the URL that's generated isn't likely to be > 2k characters. If you're buffering many points, or large line or polygon geometries then you'd need a proxy.

Another point to stress is that you should ask for results from the locator in the spatial reference of your map. This is done with the following line of code:

```
locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
```

Comment: OK thanks for reply...so far I haven't had any luck following your example.  I tried 'candidates[0]' as a parameter but no buffer is drawn (my code does work when I substitute a map click as an event parameter)...one difference I see is that you are using v3.2 of the API, but I am restricted currently to v2.1...and the locator method signature is slightly different. COuld this be part of my problem (see link http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/64790-addresss-intersection-locator-service-for-v2.1?highlight=locator+service+ArcGIS+Javascript+API+v2.1) ... Thanks, J

Comment: sorry, forgot to add my locator function: function locate() { map.graphics.clear(); var address = { "SingleLine": dojo.byId("address").value }; locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference; locator.addressToLocations(address);} /// also, I am trying to use the buffer for a query, and I seem to be limited to 400 ft.  Greater than this, and no buffer draws on the screen.  Is this related to the proxy page perhaps?

Comment: Hello, just checking in about this, I still haven't found a solution..my guess is that there is some incompatibility with v2.1 of the API, and that I may need a proxy page b/c I am using the buffer for a query..any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @JasonBK I haven't looked at this since I originally posted my answer. As far as I know, the proxy requirements haven't changed. Please do consider upgrading as it's a simple process and 2.1 is over two years old. For this specific issue, if you can provide a complete working example that reproduces the problem then I might be able to provide more help.

Comment: thanks..I am working on upgrading but I need to rewrite some of the code, including changing a ComboBox to a FilteringSelect, as the ComboBox does not seem to work with more current API versions...I may start another thread about this; so far I haven't got this switch to work...

Comment: ComboBoxes still work, but since you'll be changing Dojo versions, it's likely the API has changed.